# Levi civita notation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm having troubles with the Levi-Civita symbol. I understand what the normal epsilon-tensor means and how it works. But how do I interpret this:

$$\mathrm{{\varepsilon_{i}}^{jk}}~~~\text{or}~~~\mathrm{{\varepsilon_{ik}}^{k}}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some more context, including the definition of your "normal" epsilon? The answer really depends on the exact setting. In the case of 3-dimensional Riemannian geometry where $\varepsilon$ is a normalized volume form, this is simply the usual raising of indices using the metric.

Comment: As usual with tensors, I suspect that these are the "normal" Levi-Civita tensor with some indices raised or lowered with the aid of the metric.